# I have been working on this program for a class. Its a guessing game, any ideas on how to make the computer guess the number quicker?

Tags: python, macos

This is my second rendition where I have got the amount of guess from the computer down drastically, but I was wondering if there was a way to get it down more. It seems to have problems with the bigger number(obviously).

```
# Imports
import random

# Variables
num = 0
guess = 0
rangeStart = 0
rangeEnd = 0
counter = 0
# This set is used to keep track of the numbers that the computer has already guessed.
guesses = set()

# User Description 
print("\n\nWelcome to the guessing game!")
print("In this game you and the computer switch places.")
print("You will enter a random number between a given range(you decide).")
print("The computer will have to try and guess it.")
print("Once the computer finally guesses it, the amount of tries will be outputted")

num = int(input("\n\nEnter a number, for the computer to guess: "))
rangeStart = int(input("Enter a starting number for the range: "))

rangeEnd = int(input("Enter an ending number for the range: "))
# This while loop will trap the user from entering a number higher than the starting number.
while rangeEnd < num:
    print("Invalid answer")
    print("Your previous ending range was lower than your number. Please Try again.")
    rangeEnd = int(input("Enter an ending number for the range: "))
    
# Computer Guessing
while num != guess:
    while True:
        guess = random.randint(rangeStart, rangeEnd)
        counter += 1
        # This if statement will trap the computer from guessing the same number twice.
        if guess not in guesses:
            guesses.add(guess)
            break
    # These if and elif will tell the computer to guess higher or lower
    if guess < num:
        rangeStart = guess + 1
    elif guess > num:
        rangeEnd = guess - 1
    
    print("Computer guessed: {0:0}" .format(guess))
    
print("\nIt took the computer {0:0} guesses to get your number of {1:0}".format(counter, guess))
```

Just to lower down the amount of guesses.

Comment: You could get the computer to perform a binary search inside the interval between `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd`.

Comment: Amazing thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the computer randomly guess. Employ a binary search strategy.

If the range is 1 to 100, the computer should guess 50. If that's too high, the answer lies in the range 1 to 49. Have the computer guess 25. If that's too low it's obviously between 26 and 49. Have the computer guess 37. And so on.

At each iteration you are eliminating half of the possibilities.